# Gulping ReactJS based on environmental variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

Is it possible to have a ReactJS UI, where certain components upon compiling using Gulp are removed, depending on what the environmental variables are?

So say that my React looks as below; upon compiling with gulp, I want to use `process.env.NODE_ENV` to either compile `DevOnly` or not.

I realize that a variable and `if statement` could be used. But I prefer that this component does not show up at all in the compiled format.

```
var DevOnly = React.createClass({}) // This has to hide on Prod

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
                < div >
                    Stuff, including DevOnly (if dev)
                < / div >
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a preprocessor and it turns out gulp has one https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess

It will looks something like that (although I haven't tested it):

```
var DevOnly = React.createClass({}) // This has to hide on Prod

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
                <div>
                    <Stuff/> 
                   /* @if NODE_ENV=='dev' */ <DevOnly/> /* @endif */                   
                </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: You should write an example to help the OP though.